# Conditionally show submenu items for dropdown menu in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, submenu, aurelia

For the dropdown menu I'm creating in Aurelia, I want to check if any of the li items being displayed have a submenu item and if so, display that submenu item and make that clickable instead of the main item. Since I'm not using a router, many of the questions/answers don't necessarily fit the situation.

Here's my current html:

```
<ul class="myDropdown" id="dropdownMenu">
  <li class="myDropdown_menu-option" repeat.for="item of config.items" click.trigger="clickHandler(item.action)">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> ${item.label}
    <ul class="myDropdown__submenu-container">
      <li class="myDropdown__menu-option">
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Subitem Label
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here's my current JS (minus a few unrelated items):

```
export class Dropdown {
  parentContext;
  //config.items = [{ label:String, click:Function }]
  @bindable config = {
    items: [],
};

clickHandler( action ) {
    action.call(super.parentContext);
}
```

I guess the two things that I'm wanting to figure out are:

- Since the items will be defined by the person using this component, routes can't be defined. So I'm wondering if/how I need to define subitems so that they can be accessed, repeated through and displayed if they exist?
  Would I just be adding to my comment how they should include subitems? Something like: `config.items = [{ label:String, click: Function, subitem:[{label:String, click: Function}] }]`
- If I want to setup up a repeat for all the subitems (if they exist), how can I access those items? Would it be something like `repeat.for="subitem.item of config.items.subitem"`? I'm pretty sure that's incorrect so any pointers on that would be great.

Thanks for any guidance you can provide!

UPDATE: With the help of another person, I was able to make some changes to get the subitems to show up if they exist:

```
<ul class="myDropdown" id="dropdownMenu">
  <li class="myDropdown__menu-option" repeat.for="item of config.items" click.trigger="clickHandler(item.action)">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> ${item.label}
    <ul class="myDropdown__submenu-container">
      <li class="myDropdown__menu-option" repeat.for="subitem of items.subitems" click.trigger="clickHandler(subitems.action)">
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> ${subitem.label}
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I am filling the config object like this in my app.js file:

```
config = {
  items: [
    { label: 'Item 1', click: ()=>{}},
    { label: 'Item 2', click: ()=>{},
      subitems: [{ label: 'Subitem 2', click: ()=>{} }]
    }
  ]
};
```

So I guess the final thing I'm wondering then is how to make the click option conditional on if there is a subitem or not. For example, if there is no subitem, the item should be clickable but if there is a subitem, only the subitem should be clickable. Does the click.trigger need to called differently or on a different element so a condition can be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against a click function in your object, so that you can separate the "model" from the logic.

Use `clickHandler` in the `Dropdown` class to decide what to do based on the clicked element. e.g.

*html*

```
<li class="myDropdown__menu-option" repeat.for="item of config.items" click.delegate="clickHandler(item)">
```

*viewModel:*

```
clickHandler(item) {
    if (item.subitems && item.subitems.length > 0) {
        // do something
    }
    // by default if there are no subitems, nothing is done
}
```

You could have a separate click handler for the subitems or use the same if the action is similar - that depends on your specifics.